# Dev version connects to the live site database despite settings.php

Tags: database, configuration

I've made a dev copy of the site to perform some tests and bug fixes:

1. copied site files to the separate directory
2. copied database under the same user, so I'm able to see both DBs in the phpmyadmin
3. edited settings.php to point dev to the copied database
4. created new nginx conf to serve dev.mysite.com

BUT, the dev version is still communicates with the production DB somehow.

Server configuration:
Ubuntu, Varnish front, Nginx back, MariaDB, opcache

Site configuration: Drupal7, single-site setup

And of course, I've double checked settings.php

Christmas mystery?

Answer (score 0):

You did not edit your sites.php file or name the new site directory in such a way that Drupal can discover it.

Comment: Cilefen, it's a single-site setup, so I don't need to touch sites.php at all.

Answer (score 0):

It's Nginx misconfiguration: dev domain was pointed to the production directory